# How to convert type when I hope to get different type value from one SharedPreferences key in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

The Code B is from webpage, the Code A will cause the error "java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long".

I try to analyze reason:

First the `key="hello"` in `SharedPreferences` store the value of String, then I hope to get a value of Long from the same key, the app crash when Code B try to convert.

I think the Code B is not good, could you fix it?

I guess the code `res as T` in Code B is bad.

**Code A**

```
val key="hello"

try {
    var my1: String by PreferenceTool(this, key, "-1")
    my1 = "2"

    val my2: Long by PreferenceTool(this, key, -1L)
    var ss=my2
}catch (e:Exception){
    logError(e.message?:"None")
}
```

**Code B**

```
class PreferenceTool<T>(private val context: Context, private val name: String,  private val default: T) {

    private val prefs: SharedPreferences by lazy {       
        context.defaultSharedPreferences        
    }

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T = findPreference(name, default)

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        putPreference(name, value)
    }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    private fun findPreference(name: String, default: T): T = with(prefs) {
        val res: Any = when (default) {
            is Long -> getLong(name, default)
            is String -> getString(name, default)
            is Int -> getInt(name, default)
            is Boolean -> getBoolean(name, default)
            is Float -> getFloat(name, default)
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("This type can be saved into Preferences")
        }

        res as T
    }

    @SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
    private fun putPreference(name: String, value: T) = with(prefs.edit()) {
        when (value) {
            is Long -> putLong(name, value)
            is String -> putString(name, value)
            is Int -> putInt(name, value)
            is Boolean -> putBoolean(name, value)
            is Float -> putFloat(name, value)
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("This type can't be saved into Preferences")
        }.apply()
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the solution B is better, why you think it is not good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharedPreferences save **types** as well as key/values. For example:

```
<string name="last-version">8.clan.0h</string>
<int name="last-city" value="3" />
<boolean name="record-cached" value="true" />
```

So if you call `PreferenceTool(this, key, "-1")`, you're looking for key `hello`, which is saved as `String`, and it will work as expected.

---

But if we look into the implementation for getLong in SharedPreferences class:

```
/**
 * Retrieve a long value from the preferences.
 * 
 * @param key The name of the preference to retrieve.
 * @param defValue Value to return if this preference does not exist.
 * 
 * @return Returns the preference value if it exists, or defValue.  Throws
 * ClassCastException if there is a preference with this name that is not
 * a long.
 * 
 * @throws ClassCastException
 */
long getLong(String key, long defValue);
```

Type for key `hello` is saved as `String`, so when `PreferenceTool` calls `getLong` you will get a `ClassCastException` as documented.

You can check the documentation here:

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences

Comment: Thanks! How can I modify Code B to fix it ?

Comment: @HelloCW We can't get which type is set for given key so I'm afraid that I don't think there is an elegant solution. You can go with `(String by PreferenceTool(this, key, "-1")).toLong()`

Answer (score 0):

String in Kotlin already has an extension function you can call

```
toLong()
```

use this in your code.